# Include htm template into another one on Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, include

Actually, i have one HTML file which contains all the code. I want to split this one on multiple files and to include them.

How can i do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest you to read about components: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have this html:

```
<div class="componentA">ComponentA</div>
<div class="componentB">ComponentB</div>
```

and this code is into the `AppComponent. You can split this two div into two component:

ComponentA.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'componentA',
  templateUrl: 'componentA.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['componentA.component.scss'],

)}
export class ComponentA {

}
```

ComponentA.html

```
<div class="componentA">ComponentA</div>
```

ComponentB.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'componentB',
  templateUrl: 'componentB.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['componentB.component.scss'],

)}
export class ComponentB {

}
```

ComponentB.html

```
<div class="componentB">ComponentB</div>
```

then into your `AppComponent.html` :

```
<componentA></componentA>
<componentB></componentB>
```

Answer (score 3):

- You need to write the second *Component* - [Angular Components](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components)
- Add this component to your *App.module.ts* - [Angular Modules](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules)
- If you have business logic you can also provide this by *Services* - [Angular Services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answers above, don't forget to include

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

in your both components ts file.

Comment: it's included by default when you generate a component with  `ng generate component exampleComponent`

Comment: True but if you create it manually, you have to add it yourself.

Comment: @RagnarL I prefer to write pretty much every file myself and not to use the CLI. So yes, the "don't forget" is nice. :)